# I am getting an error while install the google map in iOS for react native version 0.71.6

Tags: react-native-maps

1. I install the google map module by the command "npm i react-native-maps".
2. In the AppDelegate.m(m) add "#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>" at the top of the page.
3. Add "[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"*YOUR_API_KEY*"];"  after "(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {"
4. change the deployment target to "13.0"
5. After that I add

   ## React Native Maps dependencies

   ## The following line is only needed if building on an Apple silicon Mac without rosetta.

   ```
   pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/Simon-TechForm/google-maps-ios-utils.git', :branch => 'feat/support-apple-silicon'
   ```

   rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
   pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

in the Podfile above "use_native_modules"
6. Then run "pod install"

I am getting an error "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "react-native-google-maps""

Here are some screenshots

[AppDelegate.m(m)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmT1s.png)

[Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJlfo.png)

[deployment target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GMoZ.png)

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCJOU.png)

I am trying to fix this issue but I can't.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?